# Run function when file downloading in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events

How can I run function when IE ask for save file localization, eg. onclick?
I google for it and found nothing interested.

```html
<a href="file.pdf" class="link">link</a>
```

```js
$(".link").on('click', function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: What is it you're attempting to do? You want to run a function during a file download that does what?

Comment: i want to run a function when someone clicks link, thats work in ff but not in ie. if i delete file extension it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a simple timing thing. When you click a link, it goes to a new page, and therefore it might not execute the function in time.

Things to try:

```
<a href="file.pdf" class="link" target="_blank">link</a>
```

This will open the link in a new window, therefore keeping you on the same page, and calling the function.

Another thing you could try is to have the download take place in the function instead of the html:

HTML:

```
<a class="link">link</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".link").on('click', function(){
    alert("test");
    //this:
   window.location.href = 'file.pdf'; //changes the current browser window to file.pdf
    //or this:   
    window.open('file.pdf', '_blank', ''); //this initiates a download, which takes place in a new window momentarily
});
```

Hopefully this helps or pushes you in the right direction.